# How to refresh automatically a list with active audience channel in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, list

I've created a filtered list with Active Audience channel. I intend to use this list in a contact deletion process. Is there any way to refresh this type of list automatically (something similar with "Refresh Mobile Filtered List") or could I do this through a script activity? Any suggestion would be very appreciated. Thanks